# Run cronjob specific hours/days

Tags: cron

I have a cronjob on my server which runs every hour all the days of the week
0 * * * *

I want to run it 09.00 - 21.00 and only from Monday to Friday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer this

```
*     *     *     *     *  Command to be executed
-     -     -     -     -
|     |     |     |     |
|     |     |     |     +----- Day of week (0-7)
|     |     |     +------- Month (1 - 12)
|     |     +--------- Day of month (1 - 31)
|     +----------- Hour (0 - 23)
+------------- Min (0 - 59)
```

> I want to run it 09.00 - 21.00 and only from Monday to Friday

Answer should be

```
* 9-21 * * 1-5
```